# Creating a percentage in an expression

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012

Would like to have some text in my report like the following where the percentage is based on an expression. I would like to know how to work out the percentage.

```
60% of letters were sent with a first class stamp
```

This is an example of the figures I'm working with

```
First Class 300
Second Class 150
Other         50
```

The fields used are 'StampType' and 'RefNo'.  The totals are gathered by a count on the 'RefNo'

Answer (score 0):

To do this, do the following steps.

First, add a new Text Box to the report. Click inside the text box so the cursor shows inside. Right-click and choose *Create Placeholder...*. Enter the following expression for the *Value* field.

```
=Lookup("First Class", Fields!StampType.Value, Fields!RefNo.Value, "ReportMain") / Sum(Fields!RefNo.Value, "ReportMain")
```

This assumes the dataset name that is returning your data is named `ReportMain`. Change this if needed.

This looks up the First Class `RefNo` value from the dataset, and then divides that by the total of the `RefNo` in the dataset.

Go to the *Number* section of the dialog, change the *Category* to *Percentage*. Adjust the *Decimal places* to your liking. Click OK.

Type the text you want to follow that value *after* the placeholder (not in the placeholder) in the text box. Like this:

[image: design mode capture]

Preview the report, and you should have what you need.

[image: preview capture]

Comment: Thanks for the excellent explanation, unfortunately when I run the report In the textbox I get #Error.  I'm assuming its to do with summing the 'RefNo'.  An example of a ref no is 22-3434.  Rather than sum that field I have tried count but still get #Error

Comment: Yeah, you can only sum numbers, and it looks like you can have strings in that field. The fact that you said *The totals are gathered by a count on the 'RefNo'* made me think it was a integer.

Comment: Could the error be because you are trying to concatenate Number with Text? Perhaps do a CSTR around the percentage or do the formatting inside the expression (format(yourvalue.value,"0%")+ "what ever text"?